# SQL select statement to find ID's that occur the most

Tags: sql

Basic SQL statement question -

I have a table (myUsers) that contains the column "UserID." The same UserID can appear one to many times in these rows. I'm looking for a query that will give me back the specific userIDs that appear the most in this table, and also with their count. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
select UserID, count(UserID)
from myUsers
group by UserID
order by count(UserID) desc
```

Comment: would change to ...order by count(userid) DESC

Comment: @Ed - you saw the post whilst I was editing - still +1 to you

Comment: You should probably see [Wil P's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1827163/26479) too - it's much more likely to work in production

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @THRESHOLD INT
SET @THRESHOLD = 20
SELECT UserID, COUNT(*)
FROM MYUSERS
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING COUNT(*) > @THRESHOLD
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

EDIT: I changed from where to having, duh totally forgot about that. :)